# LINQ indexOf a particular entry

Tags: c#, linq, indexof

I have an MVC3 C#.Net web app.  I have the below string array.

```
    public static string[] HeaderNamesWbs = new[]
                                       {
                                          WBS_NUMBER,
                                          BOE_TITLE,
                                          SOW_DESCRIPTION,
                                          HARRIS_WIN_THEME,
                                          COST_BOGEY
                                       };
```

I want to find the Index of a given entry when in another loop.  I thought the list would have an IndexOf.  I can't find it.  Any ideas?

Comment: LINQ operates on collections that do not have an index operator.  There is no `IndexOf`

Comment: @cadrell0: You can build one easily though - see my answer. There are various LINQ operators which provide the index.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Well you can use `Array.IndexOf`:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(HeaderNamesWbs, someValue);
```

Or just declare `HeaderNamesWbs` as an `IList<string>` instead - which can still be an array if you want:

```
public static IList<string> HeaderNamesWbs = new[] { ... };
```

Note that I'd discourage you from exposing an array as `public static`, even `public static readonly`. You should consider `ReadOnlyCollection`:

```
public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> HeaderNamesWbs =
    new List<string> { ... }.AsReadOnly();
```

If you ever want this for `IEnumerable<T>`, you could use:

```
var indexOf = collection.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                        .Where(pair => pair.value == targetValue)
                        .Select(pair => pair.index + 1)
                        .FirstOrDefault() - 1;
```

(The +1 and -1 are so that it will return -1 for "missing" rather than 0.)

Comment: @Jon...thanks!  Good stuff.  I like the ReadOnlyCollection idea...appreciate it

Comment: @jon-skeet Wouldn't it make more sense to make the default `-1`? `collection.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }).Where(pair => pair.value == targetValue).Select(pair => pair.index).FirstOrDefault(-1);`

Comment: @lund.mikkel: There's no overload of `FirstOrDefault` that takes a default value to supply (unlike `DefaultIfEmpty` for example).

Comment: @jon-skeet You are right! I was sure there was :( MoreLinq? ;)

Comment: `indexOf = collection.SelectMany((value, index) => value == targetValue ? new [] { index } : Enumerable.Empty<int>()).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First()`

Comment: I always find the usage of special value `-1` for "missing" smelly. Sure, theres "historic reasons", but if there was no position, then, please, make it `null`. It would also get rid of that +1/-1 fiddling.

Comment: @ImrePühvel: While I would agree if this were a green-field API, I think it's reasonable to make *this* index-of operation behave exactly the same way as every other `IndexOf` method in the framework.

Answer (score 33):

I'm late to the thread here. But I wanted to share my solution to this. Jon's is awesome, but I prefer simple lambdas for everything.

You can extend LINQ itself to get what you want. It's fairly simple to do. This will allow you to use syntax like:

```
// Gets the index of the customer with the Id of 16.
var index = Customers.IndexOf(cust => cust.Id == 16);
```

This is likely not part of LINQ by default because it requires enumeration. It's not just another deferred selector/predicate.

Also, please note that this returns the first index only. If you want indexes (plural), you should return an `IEnumerable<int>` and `yield return index` inside the method. And of course don't return -1. That would be useful where you are not filtering by a primary key.

```
  public static int IndexOf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
     
     var index = 0;
     foreach (var item in source) {
        if (predicate.Invoke(item)) {
           return index;
        }
        index++;
     }

     return -1;
  }
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to search List with a function rather than specifying an item value, you can use List.FindIndex(Predicate match).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 7):

Right `List` has IndexOf(), just declare it as `ILIst<string>` rather than `string[]`

```
public static IList<string> HeaderNamesWbs = new List<string>
                                   {
                                      WBS_NUMBER,
                                      BOE_TITLE,
                                      SOW_DESCRIPTION,
                                      HARRIS_WIN_THEME,
                                      COST_BOGEY
                                   };

int index = HeaderNamesWbs.IndexOf(WBS_NUMBER);
```

MSDN: [List(Of T).IndexOf Method (T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Generalized extension methods for getting offset(s) [aka zero-based index(es)] of any item into a collection.

```
/* by a value */
items.OffsetOf(item);
items.OffsetsOf(item);

/* by conditions */
items.OffsetOf(item => item.Id is "6174");
items.OffsetsOf(item => item.Id.StartsWith("abc"));

/* by conditions dependent from an item offset too */
items.OffsetOf((item, offset) => item.Id is "1729" && offset % 2 is 0);
items.OffsetsOf((item, offset) => item.Id.StartsWith("0") && offset % 2 is 1);
```

There is [a playground at sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

Implementation

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
        public static int OffsetOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, int, bool> match)
        {
            var offset = 0;
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                if (match(item, offset))
                    return offset;

                offset++;
            }

            return -1;
        }

        public static int OffsetOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> match) =>
            collection.OffsetOf((item, offset) => match(item));

        public static int OffsetOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, T value) =>
            collection.OffsetOf((item, offset) => item.Is(value));

        public static IEnumerable<int> OffsetsOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, int, bool> match)
        {
            var offset = 0;
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                if (match(item, offset))
                    yield return offset;

                offset++;
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> OffsetsOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> match) =>
            collection.OffsetsOf((item, offset) => match(item));

        public static IEnumerable<int> OffsetsOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, T value) =>
            collection.OffsetsOf((item, offset) => item.Is(value));
    
        public static bool Equals<T>(T a, T b) => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(a, b);
        public static bool Is<T>(this T o, T x) => Equals(o, x); /* Equals<T>(o, x); */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is guaranteed that such element exists, you could use following LINQ extension methods instead:

```
var index = items.TakeWhile(x => !condition).Count();
```

Please note that it will do 2-passes. One for TakeWhile(), another one for Count().