# Cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'System.Predicate<UnityEngine.GameObject>'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to find the index of a list item, but i can't get it to work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChunkLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] screens = {};
    public GameObject PlrSceen;
    public int chunk_index;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        chunk_index = screens.FindIndex(screens,PlrScreen);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ indexOf a particular entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300169/linq-indexof-a-particular-entry)

Answer (score 2):

[`Array.FindIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findindex?view=net-6.0#system-array-findindex-1(-0()-system-predicate((-0)))) expects a predicate to check for. This means you have to pass a method or lambda to be called. A Predicate is a method that gets passed a parameter T and returns a bool.

An example would be

```
chunk_index = screens.FindIndex(screens, go => go == PlrScreen);
```

However, I'd advise against that. You could use [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-6.0) instead, as it checks for the object instead for evaluating a predicate.